# Prove Trigonometric Identitiy

Tags: trigonometry

So we just have started to learn Trigonometric and so far we have learn these basic dentitiy
$$ \sin^2{a} + \cos^2{a} = 1 $$
$$\tan{a}=\frac{\sin{a}}{\cos{a}} $$                                                                                       $$\tan{a} .\cot{a} = 1$$

so the question is how to prove this identity:

$$\frac{\sin{a}-\cos{a} +1}{\sin{a}+\cos{a}-1} = \frac{\sin{a}+1}{\cos{a}} $$

I have tried to change $1$ to $\sin^2{a} + \cos^2{a}$ but end up with nothing.

Please someone edit my question and thank you all.

Comment: There is no absolutely correct way to do this. Whatever term you multiply and divide, for some value of $a$ it will be zero. However you will have to ignore such values if you want to obtain the identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\sin a - \cos a + 1}{\sin a + \cos a - 1}$$
$$= \frac{(\sin a - \cos a + 1)(\sin a + \cos a + 1)}{(\sin a + \cos a - 1)(\sin a + \cos a + 1)}$$
$$= \frac{\sin^2 a + 2 \sin a + 1 - \cos^2 a}{\sin^2 a + 2 \sin a \cos a + \cos^2 a - 1}$$
$$= \frac{2\sin^2 a + 2\sin a}{2 \sin a \cos a}$$
$$= \frac{\sin a + 1}{\cos a}$$

Comment: The term you are multiplying and dividing is zero for $a=-\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: @ArpanBanerjee You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Multiply and divide by $\sin{a}-(\cos{a}-1)$ .

Comment: It is not a good idea to multiply and divide by a term that can be zero for certain values. In your case, your term is zero for a = 0.

Comment: True. Though in that case, in your answer also, $\sin{a} + \cos{a} +1$ may be 0. For $a=-\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Indeed, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $\cos(a)\ne0$ and $\sin(a)+\cos(a)-1\ne0$, then cross-multiply:
$$
\begin{align}
&(\sin(a)-\cos(a)+1)\cos(a)-(\sin(a)+\cos(a)-1)(\sin(a)+1)\\
&=\small\overbrace{\color{#C00000}{\sin(a)\cos(a)}\color{#0000F0}{-\cos^2(a)}\color{#00A000}{+\cos(a)}}^{\large(\sin(a)-\cos(a)+1)\cos(a)}\overbrace{\color{#0000F0}{-\sin^2(a)}\color{#C00000}{-\sin(a)\cos(a)}\color{#C0A000}{+\sin(a)}}^{\large-(\sin(a)+\cos(a)-1)\sin(a)}\overbrace{\color{#C0A000}{-\sin(a)}\color{#00A000}{-\cos(a)}\color{#0000F0}{+1}\vphantom{1^2}}^{\large-(\sin(a)+\cos(a)-1)}\\[12pt]
&=0
\end{align}
$$
Terms of the same color cancel. The only identity we need to use is $\sin^2(a)+\cos^2(a)=1$.

Comment: Isn't the general way to prove an identity going from LHS to RHS?

Comment: @ArpanBanerjee: $\frac ab=\frac cd$ if and only if $b,d\ne0$ and $ad-bc=0$